# Add list to sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

How would I add something in sqlite to an already existing table this is what I have so far

```
>>> rid
'26539249'
>>> for t in [(rid,("billy","jim"))]:
c.execute("insert into whois values (?,?)",t)
```

How would I add onto jim and create a list? or is there some way to add onto it so It can have multiple values?

Comment: What do you mean by "add onto jim and create a list"? More generally: The whole point of relational databases like sqlite is that each value goes into its own column. You're not supposed to put a list into a column. Can you show us (the relevant part of) your database schema?

Comment: To query/search for the columns of names then generate a "whois" like database that generates all the accounts that are related to a search name then return/print the accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess here, but I suspect I'm wrong.

You can't insert `("billy", "jim")` as a column in the database. This is intentional. The whole point of RDBMSs like sqlite is that each field holds exactly one value, not a list of values. You can't search for `'jim'` in the middle of a column shared with other people, you can't join tables based on `'jim`', etc.

If you really, really want to do this, you have to pick some way to convert the multiple values into a single string, and to convert them back on reading. You can use `json.dumps`/`json.loads`, `repr`/`ast.literal_eval`, or anything else that seems appropriate. But you have to write the extra code yourself. And you won't be getting any real benefit out of the database if you do so; you'd be better off just using `shelve`.

So, I'm guessing you *don't* want to do this, and you want to know what you want to do instead.

Assuming your schema looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE whois (Rid, Names);
```

What you want is:

```
CREATE TABLE whois (Rid);
CREATE TABLE whois_names (Rid, Name, FOREIGN KEY(Rid) REFERENCES whois(Rid);
```

And then, to do the insert:

```
tt = [(rid,("billy","jim"))]
for rid, names in tt:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO whois VALUES (?)', (rid,))
    for name in names:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO whois_names VALUES (?, ?)', (rid, name))
```

Or (probably faster, but not as interleaved):

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO whois VALUES (?)', (rid for rid, names in tt))
c.executemany('INSERT INTO whois_names VALUES (?, ?),
              (rid, name for rid, names in tt for name in names))
```

Comment: I know this should be another question but would you happen to know how to keep it from insert if the same exact id and name is already in the database?

Comment: @ruler: If that's a rule that should never be violated, add a [`UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#table-constraint) (or a unique primary or foreign key) to the table. For example, `CREATE TABLE whois_names(Rid, Name, UNIQUE(Rid, Name) ON CONFLICT IGNORE, FOREIGN KEY blah blah blah`.

Comment: @ruler: If it's something that should generally be allowed, but you specifically don't want to do it in this case… you can use an [`INSERT OR IGNORE`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#insert-stmt) statement.

Comment: oh, okay. I was just wonder if it was possible to have something like this ("bob","hello") then that into ("bob",["hello","how are you"]) or something like that

Comment: @ruler: I don't think I understand that last comment. You could easily have a table of greetings, and another table mapping each person to many greetings, then write a SQL query that gets back all the greetings for a given person, then format that into a nice list in Python. Is that what you want? If so, what part do you not know how to do?

Comment: Hm, I just started sqlite3 today so I'm pretty new to everything and I don't want to waste your time telling me how to do things right but, I wouldn't mind you showing me a few websites to look at for this stuff, maybe it's up to you but thanks for your examples.

Comment: @ruler: I don't really know a good place to start learning relational databases and SQL. I started with two big textbooks on theory, and had to build a toy database server before I got to touch a real one; I wouldn't suggest doing things _that_ way (unless you end up in a time machine to the days before MySQL). The sqlite docs aren't very useful unless you already know SQL. But… there must be some good tutorials out there; maybe just google, click on a few, and find one that looks good?

Answer (score 0):

### Not tested but should do the trick

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists Data 
                (id integer primary key autoincrement, List)''')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Data (id,List) values (?,?)", 
                (lid, str(map(lambda v : v, My_list) ) ))
```